# jQuery: Finding the number of attributes an element has

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Suppose I have the xml element

```
<fruit color="blue" taste="sweet" shape="round"></fruit>
```

Without jQuery, I could use

```
fruit.attributes.length
```

How do I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `jQuery`, you'd simply retrieve the DOM element using `get(index)` or `[index]` from the `jQuery` object:

```
$('someSelector').get(0).attributes.length;
$('someSelector')[0].attributes.length;
```

`jQuery` does not provide a wrapper around this native `DOMElement` property.

Comment: I use $('root_node').children('fruit').get(0).attributes.length but it doesn't work.

Comment: Firebug doesn't have errors. However, the script stalls when it reaches that line. Perhaps, because I am parsing an xml dom object?

Comment: @Jacob .attributes doesn't work with a jQuery object I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you need to get the original DOMElement out of the jQuery set.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think jQuery has a way of doing that.  You can do it without jQuery.

```
$('fruit')[0].attributes.length
```